# Laravel error when exercising created web site

Tags: php, json, laravel

Sorry, I could not find a tag better than php and json.  I hope this gets to the right audience.

I am new to Laravel and am getting the following error with version 1.0.0.  I create a test site with the command "laravel new test" and the results indicate success. "Application ready! Build something amazing".

When I attempt to access the built site with http://sitename.com/laravel_install/test/public/ I get

ErrorException
file_put_contents(/home/public/laravel_install/test/app
/storage/meta/services.json): failed to open stream:
Permission denied
I have done a chmod 777 to all directories in the chain, but I am unable to change the permission on services.json.   This is the only file that has a different owner ("web")

I try chown owner:222222 services.json but get error message "chown: owner: illegal user name".
All of the other files and directories are owned by 222222. 
I suspect the problem is in trying to update services.json

Any suggestions as to how to get services.json created under my ownerid ? How do I get past this ?

Comment: Why not use "laravel" tag ;-?

Comment: OK, I now have a working page.  I had to chmod 777 all of the other directories under /home/public/laravel_install/test/    For example,   /bootstrap   /public   /vendor .   Brute force, I am not sure which directories had to be opened up to get it to work.  Uli Köhler, could you explain "laravel tag" please ?

Comment: You need to check whether `views` folder exists or not in `/storage/framework` directory. And also give 777 permission to `storage` folder.

Answer (score 0):

To change file ownership (assuming you are using a unix-based OS) you use

```
chown user:group file.name
```

1. You may need to sudo depending on parent directory ownership
2. user should be the user name you want to change to (ie www-data for apache in Ubuntu)
3. group should be the group name you want to change to (usually same as user)
4. you can add "-R" after chown to recursively change ownership on a directory and all of it's subdirectories

The command that you tried to run is looking for a user "owner" and group "222222" and is not finding that user in your system.

Hope that helps.

Edit:
Also, if you are using a redhat-based OS you may want to check that you have selinux running in permissive or disabled. If permissions are 777 you should be able to access the file regardless of the ownership unless the selinux context is not set correctly.

Comment: Hello iavery !    I tried                                         chown web:222222 services.json
chown: services.json: Operation not permitted                         Do I have the command entered correctly now.   Am I not allowed to make the change because I am not the owner ?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I do not know.  It looks like some variation of Unix.  It is a hosted site at nearlyfreespeech.com.

Comment: I see. There are a couple of possibilities, then. If you have sudo access to the server you can accomplish this using "sudo chown web:222222 services.json" and entering your password when prompted. 

If you don't have sudo access you will have to either use the web admin interface (the group sounds like a WebManage type of system is available) to manage the files.

Are either of those options?

Comment: I am going to call it a night !  Thanks for the correction on chown.  I will check tomorrow for any response.  Anyway, the test site now displays correctly without changing the services.json ownership.

Comment: I will try sudo and let you know.  Then to bed.

Comment: Nice idea, but sudo fails with command not found.  Bye for now.